# How do I add an MPP operation to a stim circuit using append_operation?

Tags: stim

How should I use the 'MPP' gate with append_operation in stim? For example it's clear from the documentation that circuit.append_operation('MX', [1,2]) will append two X-base measurements on qubits 1 and 2. However, I couldn't figure out how to do an X1*X2 measurement with 'MPP'. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: *Note: Got this question by email. Put here for visibility.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stim.target_x(qubit)`, `stim.target_y(qubit)`, and `stim.target_z(qubit)` to make the X, Y, and Z terms. You can use `stim.target_combiner()` to create the `*`s that join them into one product.

For example:

```
c = stim.Circuit()
c.append("MPP", [
    stim.target_x(1), stim.target_combiner(), stim.target_y(2),
    stim.target_z(3)
])
print(repr(c))

# prints:
# stim.Circuit('''
#     MPP X1*Y2 Z3
# ''')
```

(In hindsight I wish I'd designed it to use a separator instead of a combiner but it's too late to change it now.)